# Volume of Water in Hemisphere?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, volume

There is a hemispherical bowl of diameter 30 cm and it is filled with water such that the radius the top surface of water is 9 cm. Find the height of the water and and the volume of water in the bowl.
I could find the height using Pythagoras Theorem . However I cant find the volume .

Comment: I think you need some calculus to solve the problem for the volume

Comment: @gimusi so how do you do it

Comment: by integration, you can find some inspiration here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rib7yyn81BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia on spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) has the volume formula $$V=\frac 16\pi h(3a^2+h^2)$$ with a derivation.  $h$ is the height you calculated and $a$ is the radius of the base.